# Behavioral Subject Value is not seen by the feature Module when lazy loaded

Tags: angular, observable, lazy-loading, shopping-cart, behaviorsubject

I am trying to implement Shopping Cart Functionality using Angular.

product can be added to the shopping cart either through the Shopping Cart Page or through the button 'ADD TO CART' included in the Products Details page *(both consumes the same Shopping Cart Service)*

When Eagerly loading the Shopping Cart Module and Shop Module (that includes the Product Details Component Page ) it works fine.

But When Lazy loading the Shop Module, the product Details component using the Shopping Cart Service doesn't see the value being hold by the shopping cart behavioral subject and so reinitializes the shopping cart instead of updating it.

What is the PROBLEM!?.

**Shopping Cart Service**

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { take } from "rxjs/operators";
import { ICartItem } from "../../../app/shared/Interfaces/ICartItem";
import { IOrderSummary } from "../../../app/shared/Interfaces/IOrderSummary";
import { IProduct } from "../../../app/shared/Interfaces/IProduct";
import { ShoppingCart } from "../../../app/shared/Models/ShoppingCart";


@Injectable()
export class ShoppingCartService {

    baseUrl = "https://localhost:44330/api/";
   
    constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
  
    }

//shoppingCart Observable
private _shoppingCartObservable = new BehaviorSubject<ShoppingCart | null>(null);
public shoppingCartObservable$ = this._shoppingCartObservable.asObservable();

//orderSummaryObservable
private _orderSummaryObservable = new BehaviorSubject<IOrderSummary | null>(null);
public orderSummaryObservable$ = this._orderSummaryObservable .asObservable();


getShoppingCart(shoppingCartId:string){
this.http.get<ShoppingCart>(this.baseUrl+"GetShoppingCartById?id="+shoppingCartId).subscribe(
{next : shoppingCart =>{this._shoppingCartObservable.next(shoppingCart);
this.setOrderSummary(shoppingCart);
} }
)}

setShoppingCart(shoppingCart:ShoppingCart){
    this.http.post<ShoppingCart>(this.baseUrl+"UpdateShoppingCart", shoppingCart).subscribe(
    {next : shoppingCart => {this._shoppingCartObservable.next(shoppingCart)
        this.setOrderSummary(shoppingCart);
    }
    }
    )}
    
getCurrentShoppingCart(){
    return this._shoppingCartObservable.value;    //.value returns the last/current value of the Behavioral Event 
}


 addItemToCart(item: IProduct | ICartItem , qty:number=1){
   
    if ((item as ICartItem).brand ===undefined)
           item = this.mapProductToCartItem( (item as IProduct) );
     
           
    var shoppingCart = this.getCurrentShoppingCart();


        if(shoppingCart==null){
            shoppingCart = this.createShoppingCart();
        }

        shoppingCart.items = this.AddOrUpdateCartItem(shoppingCart.items, item as ICartItem, qty);
        this.setShoppingCart(shoppingCart);
    }


removeFromCart(itemId:number, qty:number=1){

let shoppingCart = this.getCurrentShoppingCart();

if(shoppingCart==null) return;

let itemToRemove = shoppingCart.items.find(i=>i.id===itemId);

if(itemToRemove){
itemToRemove.qty -= qty;

if(itemToRemove.qty <=0)
shoppingCart.items = shoppingCart.items.filter(i=>i.id !== itemId);

}

if(shoppingCart.items.length <=0){
    this.removeShoppingCart(shoppingCart)
}else{
    this.setShoppingCart(shoppingCart);
}

}
   
    
    //private helper methods
    private mapProductToCartItem(item:IProduct):ICartItem{

        return { id : item.id,
            productName: item.productName,
            price: item.salesPrice,
            qty: 0,
            pictureUrl:item.pictureUrl,
            brand: item.brandName,
            type: item.categoryName      
        };
    };

    private createShoppingCart(){
        const shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
        localStorage.setItem("shoppingCartId",shoppingCart.id);
        return shoppingCart;
    }

    private AddOrUpdateCartItem(shoppingCartItems:ICartItem[], cartItem:ICartItem, qty:number){

    const cartItemToAddOrUpdate  = shoppingCartItems.find(i=>i.id===cartItem.id);   

    if(cartItemToAddOrUpdate){
        cartItemToAddOrUpdate.qty += qty;
    }
    else{
        cartItem.qty = qty;
        shoppingCartItems.push(cartItem);
    }

return shoppingCartItems;

    }

private setOrderSummary(shoppingCart:ShoppingCart){

        if(!shoppingCart)
                return;
        
                let totalqty = 0;
                let totalPrice = 0;
                let shipping = 0;
        
                shoppingCart.items.forEach(item=>{
                    totalqty += item.qty;
                    totalPrice += item.qty * item.price;
                } )
        
        let orderSummary:IOrderSummary = {
            shipping: shipping,
            totalPrice: totalPrice,
            subTotal: totalPrice + shipping,
            totalQty : totalqty
        }
        
        this._orderSummaryObservable.next(orderSummary);        
        }
        
private removeShoppingCart(shoppingCart:ShoppingCart){
this.http.delete(this.baseUrl+"DeleteShoppingCart?id="+shoppingCart.id);
this._shoppingCartObservable.next(null);
this._orderSummaryObservable.next(null);
localStorage.removeItem("shoppingCartId")

}

}
```

**ProductDetailsComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { IProduct } from 'src/app/shared/Interfaces/IProduct';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/core/Services/ProductService';
import { ShoppingCartService } from 'src/app/core/Services/ShoppingCartService';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-details',
  templateUrl: './product-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-details.component.scss']
})
export class ProductDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  product:IProduct;
  productId:number;

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,
    private _productsService:ProductService,
    private _shoppingCartService:ShoppingCartService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.params.subscribe( (params:Params)=>{
    this.productId = params['id'];
    })

    this.getProduct();

  }

  getProduct(){
    this._productsService.getProductById(this.productId).subscribe((data)=>{
this.product = data;
    })
  }

  addToCart(){

   if(this.product){
    this._shoppingCartService.addItemToCart(this.product);
    console.log('added from productdetails');
  }

  }

}
```

**ShopModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ProductDetailsComponent } from './product-details/product-details.component';
import { ProductItemComponent } from './product-item/product-item.component';
import { ShopPageComponent } from './shop-page/shop-page.component';
import { SHAREDModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


const routes:Routes=[
  {path:'',component:ShopPageComponent},
  {path:':id',component:ProductDetailsComponent}
  ]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ProductDetailsComponent, ProductItemComponent, ShopPageComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SHAREDModule,
   RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports:[RouterModule]
  })
export class ShopModule { }
```

**AppRoutingModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home/home-page/home-page.component';


const routes: Routes = [
{path:'',component:HomePageComponent},
{path:"Shop", loadChildren:()=>import('./Shop/shop.module').then(m=>m.ShopModule)},
{path:"Account", loadChildren:()=>import('./authentication/authentication.module').then(m=>m.AuthenticationModule)}
//{path:'**',redirectTo:"/",pathMatch:'full'}

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

 }
```

**AppModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { OrderModule } from './order/order.module';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';

import { ShoppingCartModule } from './ShoppingCart/shopping-cart.module';

import { COREModule } from './core/core.module';
import { SHAREDModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { ShopModule } from './Shop/shop.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    OrderModule,
    HomeModule,
    ShoppingCartModule,
    
    COREModule,
    SHAREDModule,
  ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**AppComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountService } from './core/Services/account.service';
import { ShoppingCartService } from './core/Services/ShoppingCartService';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
cardId : string;
token : string;
title:string = 'Coffee Corner';


  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getCurrentCart();   
   this.getCurrentUser(); 
   
  }
 
constructor(private _shoppingCartService:ShoppingCartService, private _accountService:AccountService) {
}

getCurrentCart(){
  this.cardId = localStorage.getItem("shoppingCartId")

  if(this.cardId!=null){
       this._shoppingCartService.getShoppingCart(this.cardId);
     }
}

getCurrentUser(){
  this.token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  this._accountService.loadCurrentUser(this.token).subscribe(); 
}


}
```

Comment: If you change your injectable attribute on your service to have the `providedIn:'root'` option, does that fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Here Module re-initializes the service on lazy load which is holding the behavioral subject.**
So, making the service available at the root (can be accessed without importing in providers in **ngModule**) will not re-initialize the behavioral subject.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
class ShopingCartService {}
```

Comment: I added that   @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
to the ShoppingCartService and still got the same problem .

Comment: @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
}). And Do not load/import this ShoppingCartService  in any module as we have given providedIn : 'root'. If  need this service then just use it directly via dependency injection method in angular.